# Extending pygame sprite class

Tags: python, class, pygame

So I'm writing a game in python with pygame, and I have separate classes (of the type pygame.sprite.Sprite) for my different sprites - however they all share a lot of common physics code. How can I extend the basic sprite class, so that common physics stuff is written once, and I just add class specific stuff to each sprite class needed?

e.g. Change from this:

```
class ShipSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, start_position=(500,500)):
        # Call the sprite initialiser
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        init_stuff()

    def common_physics_stuff()
        pass

    def ship_specific_stuff()
        pass

class AsteroidSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, start_position=(500,500)):
        # Call the sprite initialiser
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        init_stuff()

    def common_physics_stuff()
        pass

    def asteroid_specific_stuff()
        pass
```

Into this

```
class my_custom_class()
    def common_physics_stuff()
        pass

class ShipSprite(my_custom_class):

    def __init__(self, start_position=(500,500)):
        # Call the sprite initialiser
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        init_stuff()

    def ship_specific_stuff()
        pass

class AsteroidSprite(my_custom_class):

    def __init__(self, start_position=(500,500)):
        # Call the sprite initialiser
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        init_stuff()

    def asteroid_specific_stuff()
        pass
```

Comment: Can't you just use `my_custom_class(pygame.sprite.Sprite)` to make your custom one inherit from the base class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just inherit your intermediate class from `Sprite`, and inherit from it thereafter:

```
class my_custom_class(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def common_physics_stuff()
        pass

class ShipSprite(my_custom_class):
    ...
```

If you would like to add your "custom_class" things to a somewhat abstract class that does not have to behave like a Sprite, and could be used in other contexts, you could make use of Multiple Inheritance as well -

```
class my_custom_class(object):
    def common_physics_stuff()
        pass

class ShipSprite(pygame.sprite.Sprite, my_custom_class):
    ...
```

But that would probably be overkill - in any of these two cases, on any method you override on your game classes, just remember to call the proper ancestor method uisng the  `super` Python builtin.

(On my small game projects I usually do a "GameObject" base class for all my objects which inherit from Pygame's Sprite)